# Concatenation of user products based in conditions

Tags: spss

I'm trying to concatenate string variables based in some conditions. Suppose the following data to ilustrate.

```
DATA LIST FREE /USER_ID(F2.0) SHOP(A5) PRODUCT(A8).
BEGIN DATA
1 SHOP1 PRODUCT1
1 SHOP1 PRODUCT2
1 SHOP2 PRODUCT1
1 SHOP2 PRODUCT4
2 SHOP1 PRODUCT1
2 SHOP2 PRODUCT2
2 SHOP3 PRODUCT3
END DATA.

AUTORECODE SHOP PRODUCT /INTO COD_SHOP COD_PRODUCT.
DELETE VARIABLES SHOP PRODUCT.
RENAME VARIABLES COD_SHOP = SHOP.
RENAME VARIABLES COD_PRODUCT = PRODUCT.
EXECUTE.
```

What I want to do is for the same `USER_ID` and `SHOP` create a new variable called `BOUGHT` with the names of the products, following some rules.

For the same `USER_ID` and `SHOP`:

```
PRODUCT1 THEN BOUGHT IS 'PRODUCT1'
IF PRODUCT4 THEN BOUGHT IS 'PRODUCT4'
IF PRODUCT1 AND PRODUCT4 THEN BOUGHT IS 'PRODUCT1 + PRODUCT4'
 IF PRODUCT2 OR PRODUCT3 THEN BOUGHT IS 'PRODUCT MIX'.
```

What I tried

```
IF (PRODUCT = 1) USER_PRODUCT_1 = 1.
IF (PRODUCT = 2) USER_PRODUCT_2 = 1.
IF (PRODUCT = 3) USER_PRODUCT_3 = 1.
IF (PRODUCT = 4) USER_PRODUCT_4 = 1.

SORT CASES BY USER_ID SHOP.
AGGREGATE
/OUTFILE *
/BREAK = USER_ID SHOP
/PRODUCT1 = MAX(USER_PRODUCT_1)
/PRODUCT2 = MAX(USER_PRODUCT_2)
/PRODUCT3 = MAX(USER_PRODUCT_3)
/PRODUCT4 = MAX(USER_PRODUCT_4)
.
```

This way I will know for the same `USER_ID` and `SHOP` the products that were bought. Then to create the variable `BOUGHT`

```
STRING BOUGHT(A60).
DO IF (PRODUCT1 = 1). BOUGHT = 'PRODUCT1'
ELSE IF. (PRODUCT4 =1) BOUGHT = 'PRODUCT4'
ELSE IF. (PRODUCT1 = 1 & PRODUCT4 = 1) BOUGHT = 'PRODUCT1 + PRODUCT4'.
ELSE. BOUGHT = 'PRODUCT MIX'
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

This is just a simple example. I have more products than this, where some are grouped with some specific name in the final variable BOUGHT, but the others need to be concatenated. Using IF conditions in this case would require a lot of work. How I could do that?

Comment: There are some improvements to your syntax so far (eg you should look up `do repeat`) but I can't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Getting a text like 'PRODUCT1 + PRODUCT4' should be easy enough, but you'll need to better explain what are the rules for "PRODUCT MIX"

Answer (score 0):

I think to the extent you have conditions, you will likely need to use `IF` to some degree. Without knowing the specific "Product" combinations you need to accommodate I will make my best attempt to offer a general approach.

Let's assume you have 8 products. We'll aggregate them to the `USER_ID` by `SHOP` level as you did (although skipping the intermediary step of creating individual PRODUCT variables).

```
SORT CASES BY USER_ID SHOP.
AGGREGATE
 /OUTFILE=*
 /PRESORTED
 /BREAK = USER_ID SHOP
 /PRODUCT1 = CIN(PRODUCT,1,1)
 /PRODUCT2 = CIN(PRODUCT,2,2)
 /PRODUCT3 = CIN(PRODUCT,3,3)
 /PRODUCT4 = CIN(PRODUCT,4,4)
 /PRODUCT5 = CIN(PRODUCT,5,5)
 /PRODUCT6 = CIN(PRODUCT,6,6)
 /PRODUCT7 = CIN(PRODUCT,7,7)
 /PRODUCT8 = CIN(PRODUCT,8,8) .
```

Now let's create the variable `BOUGHT` to track all the product combinations that might occur for a given `USER_ID` and `SHOP`.

```
STRING BOUGHT(A100) .
VECTOR PRODUCT = PRODUCT1 TO PRODUCT8 .
LOOP #i=1 TO 8 .
IF (BOUGHT ='' AND PRODUCT(#i)>0) BOUGHT=CONCAT('Product ',#i) .
IF (BOUGHT~='' AND PRODUCT(#i)>0) BOUGHT=CONCAT(BOUGHT,' + Product ',#i) .
END LOOP .
EXE .
```

To apply custom values for particular product combinations you can use `RECODE`. Let's assume you need custom values for product combinations [2,5] and [3,6,8].

```
RECODE BOUGHT
 ('Product 2 + Product 5' = 'Some Product Combo')
 ('Product 3 + Product 6 + Product 8' = 'Some Other Product Combo') .
EXE .
```

Keep in mind that if you have more products (and potential combinations) that you'll want to allow `BOUGHT` to accommodate more characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get to an easier solution if you restructure your data with vars to cases.

```
SORT CASES BY USER_ID SHOP PRODUCT.

CASESTOVARS
  /ID=USER_ID SHOP
  /INDEX=PRODUCT
  /GROUPBY=VARIABLE
  /VIND ROOT=idx.
```

Keep in mind, that in order to do this every combination of id and shop must be unique in your dataset.

After this comand your data would look like this:

```
USER_ID SHOP idxPRODUCT1 idxPRODUCT2 idxPRODUCT3 idxPRODUCT4
1       1    1           1           0           0 
1       2    1           0           0           1
2       1    1           0           0           0
2       2    0           1           0           0
2       3    0           0           1           0
```

I'm not sure what you exactly want to do with the 'bought' variable. But let's say you want to create a string variable that concats all the products that a user bought in a shop. Then you could do this as following:

```
STRING bought (A120).
IF (idxproduct1) bought = 'product1'.
IF (idxproduct2) bought = CONCAT(bought, ' + ', 'product2').
IF (idxproduct3) bought = CONCAT(bought, ' + ', 'product3').
IF (idxproduct4) bought = CONCAT(bought, ' + ', 'product4').
...
* Remove any leading ' + '.
IF(CHAR.INDEX(bought, ' + ') = 1) bought = REPLACE(bought, ' + ', '', 1).

EXECUTE.
```